# Json Data Not mapped in the backend service

Tags: json, web-services, spring, post, spring-mvc

I have  a Spring MVC web application and I have the following web service.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newBill", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ModelMap acceptNewBill(@ModelAttribute ("Bill") Bill newBill ){
    Bill bill = new Bill();

    bill.setTableName(newBill.getTableName());
    bill.setRoom(newBill.getRoom());
    bill.setCovers(newBill.getCovers());

    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.put("status", true);
    return model;
}
```

The following Script performs the front end functions.

```
$('.done').click(function(){
var jsonObject = createJSON(".newBill");

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/newBill",
    type: "POST",
    data: {bill: JSON.stringify(jsonObject) },
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function(x) {
    if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
        x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('sadgsd');
        }
    });
});

function createJSON(elementToConvert) {
    jsonObj = [];
    $( elementToConvert + " input").each(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("class");
    var email = $(this).val();

    item = {}
    item [id] = email;

    jsonObj.push(item);
    });

    return jsonObj;
}
```

The above createJSON function go through a provided html element and puts the values into an object! The click function performs the POST and the Post contains the following data.

```
bill    [{"tableName":"326432"},{"room":"3462346"},{"covers":"3426234"}]
```

Now when I debug and check the service, the data which goes from the front end doesn't get mapped in the parameter. I checked whether the variable names are the same as the POST.  They are the same! but the values doesn't get mapped! Can any one please help me with this issue.

Update :

I changed the service method to GET and passed a value as a URL variable. Then it got mapped in the service param. The problem is in the POST.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `@ModelAttribute` in your controller use `@RequestBody`:

```
public @ResponseBody ModelMap acceptNewBill(@RequestBody Bill newBill) {
```

On the ajax call, set the content type to `application/json` and stringify the whole object instead of just the array:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/newBill",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({bill: jsonObject}),
    dataType: "application/json",
    beforeSend: function(x) {
        if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
            x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
        }
    },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('sadgsd');
    }
});
```